# Charts with Sharp Develop and SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, charts

I'm inprocess to create a simple application that draws chart using the data from SQLite. Is it possible ? I'm trying to go

this way for developing application:

1. connecting and processing data using SQLite
2. Fetching SQLite data for chart control and display results on chart

I'm using C# with sharp develop for this simple project.

Any pointers or suggestions for this?

Answer (score 4):

I've had very good experience with [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), an LGPL charting/graphing library.  The API is very straightforward, and the UserControl supplied by them allows saving the chart as an image, printing, manual scroll/zoom, etc.

Whether you're using SQLite or anything else to obtain your data is more or less unrelated to how you display the data.  ZedGraph essentially just takes in pairs of x/y coordinates, so it doesn't care where you get your data.

Comment: I agree. I work with ZG for about a year now and it does its job. I needed to make just few small modifications as my soft required functionality that ZG does not provide by default.